# Custom unicode combining char

Tags: postscript, opentype, fontforge

I'm trying to create a font with some special features I need with FontForge. I've already created some custom ligatures, but I also need custom combining characters. When I put custom shape on standart combining character's place (U+0300–U+036F) Firefox, which I use as standart font renderer (because font will be used with it), shows symbol from other font in right place (under prev char), and when I assign to any of Private use area, it simply don't show.

AND when I try to solve it with GPOS, all my ligatures become broken (when I add Anchor point to any character).

Some characters I need:

(ligature) T + ` =  T with diagonal crossed stem
T + [custom combining char] = T with small 3 below
T + ` + [custom combining char] = T with small 3 below AND diagonal crossed stem

(sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 0):

Does the letter combination work in a program that supports opentype features? Like Indesign? Be sure the feature you use is also executed by the browser. Firefox may need some css to enable ligatures:

```
font-feature-settings: "liga""dlig";
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
```